# Is my SSD okay?:

Tags: linux

`iostat -xk 5` shows this:

```
           1.31   10.63    3.99   14.21    0.00   69.86

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda            2942.00   497.40 1755.00  414.60 19107.20  3695.20    21.02    86.19   41.18   0.40  86.96
sdb              62.40   519.00  137.40   73.00  2459.20  2372.00    45.92     1.04    4.95   2.03  42.72

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.54   10.23    4.90   14.27    0.00   68.05

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda            8936.80   395.00 2752.80    4.00 48004.80  1596.00    35.98     3.90    1.41   0.30  83.70
sdb             393.40   491.00  238.80   76.00  4984.80  2268.00    46.08     4.65   14.79   1.52  48.00
```

What does `await 14.79` mean? Is the unit milliseconds, seconds or something else?
What does `svctime` mean? Is the unit milliseconds, seconds or something else?

Answer (score 1):

`await` - it's the average time for I/O requests issued to the device. Both spent in the queue waiting for processing and served by the device. (in milliseconds) 
 This includes the time spent by the requests in queue and the time spent servicing them.

`svctime(svctm)` - it's the average service time for I/O requests sent to the device. (in milliseconds)

Actually the await is a sum of svctime and wait queue:

```
await = svctime + wait time in queue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find such information in the manpages for [`iostat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) i.e. `man iostat`:

> **Reports**
>
> ...
>
> *Device Utilization Report*
>
> ...
>
> **await**
>
> The average time (in milliseconds) for I/O requests issued to the device to be served. This includes the time spent by the requests in
>   queue and the time spent servicing them.
>
> **svctm**
>
> The average service time (in milliseconds) for I/O requests that were issued to the device. Warning! Do not trust this field any more.
>   This field will be removed in a future sysstat version.
>
> **Bugs**
>
> ...
>
> The average service time (svctm field) value is meaningless, as I/O
>   statistics are calculated at block level, and we don't know when the
>   disk driver starts to process a request. For this reason, this field
>   will be removed in a future sysstat version.

It's not clear why you imply there might be a problem with your disk, but looking at such iostat information is not very insightful. If you think you have an issue with a disk, maybe look at your logs in `/var/log` to see if there are error messages, then see [`fsck`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) to check the filesystem on disk and maybe something like [`smartctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl) from the smartmontools package to check the low level smart health of your disk if it supports such capabilities.